# how to check in iphone application if there is any data in sqlite data base

Tags: iphone, xcode, web-services

how to check at the start of the app wether there is data in sqlite or not if data is available in data base then it should upload other wise normally work the application

i will upload this data using post and using php for to upload data to server.

```
     + (void) getInitialDataToDisplay:(NSString *)dbPath {

CereniaAppDelegate *appDelegate = (CereniaAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

    const char *sql = "select response_Id,question_id,answer_option,answer_text,update_date_time from survey_question_responses";



    sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            NSInteger primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
            Coffee *coffeeObj = [[Coffee alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey];
            coffeeObj.question_Id = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)];
            coffeeObj.answer_text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 2)];
            coffeeObj.answer_option = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,3)];

            coffeeObj.update_date_time = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 4)];
            int count=[appDelegate.coffeeArray count];

            NSLog(@"count is beofore getting values %d",count);




            [appDelegate.coffeeArray addObject:coffeeObj];



            int countone=[appDelegate.coffeeArray count];

            NSLog(@"count is after getting values %d",countone);

            [coffeeObj release];
        }
       }
     }
     else
    sqlite3_close(database); //Even though the open call failed, close the    database connection to release all the memory.
       }
```

Comment: You can fire the Select * query and check out whether the data is present or not ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get number of rows present into the database by:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table;
```

if it returns 0 then your table is empty.

//update...................

```
      const char *sqlQuery="Select count(*)from yourTable";
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlQuery, -1, &queryStatement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(queryStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) 
        {

            const char *count=(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(queryStatement, 0);
           NSString *rowCount=[NSString stringWithCString:count encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

       //here you will get the number of rows in string format;


        }

    }
```

Comment: mean i have to write this querry in other method

Comment: I have tested this code before posting. Please show your NSLog statement.

Comment: Why are you getting the count as a string and not an integer?  Also you don't clean-up the statement object.